# FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+ when I try to enable KVM on WSL on Windows 10

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to enable KVM on WSL2 on Windows 10 x64 bit. I've found this tutorial and I'm following it :

https://gist.github.com/offlinehacker/b1d96515f87a47bd0b0bea574eab5583

I've cloned and compiled the WSL2 kernel on a vmware VM with this command as suggested by the tutorial :

make KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl -j8

It reached the end without errors and the vmlinux file has been produced. So,according with the instructions,I have placed it on /users/marietto2020/ with the other file .wslconfig. So,I went on with the instructions,like that :

1) Copy run-wsl.bat, attach.wdbg and patch_wsl_nested.js to same folder

2) Fix path in attach.wdbg

3) Open admin powershell in that folder

4) Run ./run-wsl.bat and follow instructions

and this is what happened :

```
ziomario@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/b1$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT: sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT: sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok


ziomario@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/b1$ su
Password:


root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/b1# kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT: sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module msr not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+


root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/b1# sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+# cp /mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/arch/x86/kvm/* /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+# ls /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+

kvm-amd.ko kvm-intel.ko kvm.ko

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+# sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module kvm_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard+
```

IT IS NOT RECOGNIZED ! do u know the reason ?